# Mobile to backend authentication

Tags: authentication, facebook-login, access-token

I am trying to implement a login for my mobile app to my backend. I previously used to use a method that required hashing on mobile site and backend site. The password would be hashed saved on the mobile site and be included in the hash. If hashes on mobile side and backend side would be equal, the request would be valid.

However I wanted to add Facebook login to my login system so I kinda find out it was not gonna work the way I had built it before. I came to the conclusion that I probably have to change the entire method to token login.

What I have currently functioning is Facebook button on mobile side, this creates for me a Facebook userid and Facebook access token. I send both these values to my backend and use a Facebook graph call to retrieve the facebookid from the access token. if both the Facebook userids are equal. I either register the user or log him in.

This is where I get stuck. I now want to generate my own token to send back to the mobile side, because I have custom login (email+password) (Facebook is just an option). So I think using my own auth token for both ways is the best.

I have a few questions about this token:

- What should the token exist of?
- Do I need to save this token on the mobile (not hashed?)
- What is the best way to built in expiring time and automatic refresh token

What I can't really understand is the security of this authentication method. Sending a token over a request that gives you access to user information is just as bad as a plain password I think? Is SSL connection simply enough?

I understand these are a lot of question in one but I hope someone can give me a clear explanation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JWT](http://jwt.io/) (JSON web token), it's really simple. The idea its, when you do the login, the servers return you the JWT and you simply have to save it in your mobile app. Then you have to pass it as a header (assuming you are developing for Android):

```
request = new HttpGet();
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Global.loginData.jwt);
```